# How can I deal with not approved pull requests with feature dependencies?

Tags: git, branch, pull-request, git-flow

Suppose i have a **feature A** and make a push to the remote server and then a PR with **develop** branch, then someone assign to me **feature B** which it needs some of the code on **feature A**, but **feature A** is not approved yet.

How can i manage this? Should i create a new local branch upon feature **A** instead of **develop**? Or what would be the best practice?

By the way, I'm using gitflow workflow

Comment: Related https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351727/working-on-a-branch-with-a-dependence-on-another-branch-that-is-being-reviewed

Comment: Why not just wait until `feature A` is approved?

Comment: Thanks @AdamMillerchip that would work

Comment: @johannchopin i have to work on feature B